# Show truncated value in text input, but eventually store full value in the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Is there a way to show for instance two decimals in a text input (e.g. 0.00), but store four decimals in the database (e.g. 0.0001). I tried to use toFixed(2); but the problem is that toFixed "really" shortens decimals to two (in this case) resulting in storing only the two decimals in the database, when a $_POST is done to insert data.

What I really want is to show 0.00 in the textinput to the user, but store the real value which is 0.0001 in the database.

How to achieve this?

Comment: your requirement is bit confusing. Do you want to display 0.00 after retrieving from database or before storing to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?

Keep your textbox like this, which is visible in front end

`<input type="text" name="front_value" value="0.00" />`

and beside above textbox create one hidden field like this, which will store exact value for inserting in the database.

`<input type="hidden" name="db_value" value="0.0001" />`

While submitting form you can use `$_POST['db_value']`